# Change order of columns when window shrinks

Tags: html, css

I have 2 columns, left and right. When the window shrinks I'd like for the right column to be shown above the left column.

Right now when the window shrinks, the right pops down under the left.

How can I change it so that the right column moves to the top of the left column when the window shrinks?

Here's a fiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/1m6n2dz8/1/

```
.descright {
float: right;
width: 40%;
}
.descleft {
float:left;
width:60%;
}
.group {
margin:0 6%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.descleft, .descright {
float: none;
width: auto;
}
}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Switch the order of the html elements and you're done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply swap the order of your HTML columns.

```css
.descright {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
}
.descleft {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}
.group {
  margin: 0 6%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .descleft,
  .descright {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <div class="descright">Right</div>
  <div class="descleft">Left</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The easy way is just to put the right column first in the HTML source order. In the near future, we'll have grid layouts that give more flexibility in this respect, but they are not ready yet.

Comment: What do you mean, "in the future"?  CSS4?

Comment: There isn't really a CSS3 or CSS4 as such, but rather modules. The CSS Grid module is currently Level 1: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-grid/ It's sort of supported in IE11 at this stage: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid … so it's not far off widespread usage.

Answer (score 2):

To get that layout you maybe want to reorder your markup, and add some `left` properties to swap the columns on larger widths:

```css
.descright {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  left: -60%;
}
.descleft {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  left: 40%;
}
.group {
  margin: 0 6%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .descleft,
  .descright {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <div class="descright">
    Right
  </div>
  <div class="descleft">
    Left
  </div>
</div>
```